# Can I INSERT into a sharded table at the same time through the distributed table and on individual shards?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a Clickhouse cluster with 4 shards and a distributed table that reads/writes on all of them. The sharding key is defined so that records written are evenly distributed.
Most of the times I write through the distributed table. At time I would like an INSERT to go onto a specific shard (the `insert_shard_id` setting is not yet an option because I am still on 20.3.9 version that does not support that setting).

Is there any downside in mixing INSERTS to the distributed tables with inserts into the individual nodes on the same cluster? (or is it supposed to work at all) ?

Context on the use cases. The table is a replacing merge tree and at times I would like to write a new version of a record written before. Though after increasing the number of shards, the new data is going to be distributed in a different way than before, so a new version of a record is unlikely to end on the same shard where the previous version was and the two will never be merged.

Thanks
Filippo

Comment: No downsides. Supported.

Comment: what about possible data duplication, @DennyCrane?

Comment: @VictorPerov I don't understand your question. Filippo is going to use direct insertion into targeted shard to make "deduplication" work.

Comment: @VictorPerov, maybe this parts was missing from my question. I am not writing the same data both via the distributed table and via the direct insert. I am doing some inserts in one way and other inserts in another. Never writing the same rows twice.